# New to Java and having issues with linking scrapbook to constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm trying to follow along to the Eclipse Java tutorials (lesson 3 at the moment) which introduces trying to import packages into a scrapbook. In this case it's supposed to mean that I can call

```
Person p = new Person();
p
```

instead of

```
Person p = new org.totalbeginner.tutorial.Person();
p
```

But, even though I've followed each step one by one, I get a "null" result in the inspection view rather than the expected class fields in the inspector (which should be 'name' and 'maximumBooks')

Here is the class 'Person':

```
package org.totalbeginner.tutorial;

public class Person {
    // fields
    private String name; // name of the person
    private int maximumBooks; // maximum books a person can check out

    //constructor (initial values)
    public Person() {
        name = "unknown name";
        maximumBooks = 3;
    }

    //methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String anyName) {
        name = anyName;
    }

    public int getMaximumBooks() {
        return maximumBooks;
    }

    public void setMaximumBooks(int maximumBooks) {
        this.maximumBooks = maximumBooks;
    }


}
```

Now the tutorial is using an outdated version of Eclipse. I followed the following procedure to import a package into the scrapbook:

1. Click on 'Sets the Import Declarations for Running Code' shortcut
2. Add Packages...
3. Selected 'org.totalbeginner.tutorial.*' and press OK.

Is there a different step I'm missing? Neither the Person class or the Scrapbook have any noted compiling errors. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: what are you printing to the console?

Comment: @BatScream sorry should have clarified: not printing anything, just using 'Inspect'. The "null" appears in the inspect view. Edited post to fix this.

Comment: Okay the problem is in the way you debug, write a line below Person p = new org.totalbeginner.tutorial.Person();, as System.out.println(); Now when you are debugging press F6, to step to the next line. This allows the execution of the first statement to be complete. With the debugger on the print statement, inspect the value of 'p'.

Comment: Your problem isn't related to importing the `Person` class — if your code was referring to a class that hadn't been imported,  you'd get a compile error.

Comment: @BatScream I now have Person p = new org.totalbeginner.tutorial.Person(); then newline then System.out.println(); newline then p. If I then press 'Inspect' it shows up as ""= (No explicit return value) and beneath that it says "null". You say the problem is the way I debug, but I'm just following the tutorial and his shows up fine. If I press F6 whilst doing this, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scrapbook Page](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31789&seqNum=3)(.jpage) doesn't reside inside your package and it only evaluates expressions

The imports must be done using

`Set the Import Declarations for the Running Code button` next to Terminate button menu ->Add Packages->Select your Package

[image]

```
Person p = new Person();
p
```

Select all 2 lines and Inspect to see the result in expression view

[image]

Comment: Ah. Didn't select the lines! Is that necessary just because 'Inspect' will only look at portions of the code?

Comment: I think it is because `Inspect` needs complete picture i.e information about the object